# VBA Runtime error 440 Shapes.Count Failed

Tags: excel, vba

Im getting a runtime error everytime i try to run my code below. Any idea why or suggestions on how to fix? Im just trying to search a folder for pptx files that contain matching keyword in any of the slides and recording the matching ppt file names in the worksheet:

```vb
 Sub SearchAndWriteToWorksheet()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim keyword As String
    Dim pptFileName As String
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pptPres As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rowNum As Long
    
    ' Set folder path and keyword
    folderPath = "C:\Users\40005047\Desktop\CodeTest" ' Change this to your folder path
    keyword = "EAR" ' Change this to your keyword
    
    ' Set up worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("results") ' Change "Sheet1" to your worksheet name
    ws.Cells.Clear
    rowNum = 1
    
    ' Open each PowerPoint file in the folder
    pptFileName = Dir(folderPath & "\*.pptx")
    Do While pptFileName <> ""
        found = False
        
        ' Open PowerPoint application
        Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
        pptApp.Visible = True ' You can set this to True to see the PowerPoint files being opened
        
        ' Open PowerPoint presentation
        Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(folderPath & "\" & pptFileName)
        
        ' Search for keyword in slides
        For Each slide In pptPres.slides
            For Each Shape In slide.Shapes
                If Shape.HasTextFrame Then
                    If InStr(1, Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, keyword, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        found = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next Shape
            If found Then Exit For
        Next slide
        
        ' Close PowerPoint presentation and application
        pptPres.Close
        pptApp.Quit
        
        ' Write filename to worksheet if keyword is found
        If found Then
            ws.Cells(rowNum, 1).Value = pptFileName
            rowNum = rowNum + 1
        End If
        
        ' Get next PowerPoint file in the folder
        pptFileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    ' Clean up
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Search complete. Results written to worksheet."
End Sub
```

Im not sure how to fix this error

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: on the line pptApp.Quit

Comment: `Shape` is a reserved keyword of VBA. Please don't use it as a variable name. I haven't seen `Shapes.Count` in your code snippet.

Comment: Ok how do i use Shapes.count in the code? Or how do i get vba to read the slide without using Shape

Comment: @ShannonMcKinley try to use an other variable name for Shape (e.g. pptShape) and Slide (e.g. pptSlide) object

Comment: @Shrotter can you show me using the code ive provided? Im totally lost

Answer (score 0):

It could be a timing issue.  I would suggest pausing your macro at certain times (ie. after opening PowerPoint, opening a Presentation, etc).

Also, there's no need to create a new instance of PowerPoint each time you open/close a presentation.  Simply create one instance prior to looping through your files, and then quit the application afterwards.

Also, as already mentioned, Shape and Slide are reserved keywords.  So use different names for those variables.

Here's an example.  First, add the following procedure to your module...

```
Sub PauseMacro(ByVal secs As Long)

    Dim endTime As Single
    endTime = Timer + secs
    
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Timer > endTime
    
End Sub
```

Then amend your macro as follows...

```
 Sub SearchAndWriteToWorksheet()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim keyword As String
    Dim pptFileName As String
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pptPres As Object
    Dim pptSlide As Object
    Dim pptShape As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rowNum As Long
    
    ' Set folder path and keyword
    folderPath = "C:\Users\40005047\Desktop\CodeTest" ' Change this to your folder path
    keyword = "EAR" ' Change this to your keyword
    
    ' Get the first pptx file
    pptFileName = Dir(folderPath & "\*.pptx")
    If Len(pptFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No .pptx files found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Set up worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("results") ' Change "Sheet1" to your worksheet name
    ws.Cells.Clear
    rowNum = 1
    
    ' Open PowerPoint application
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    pptApp.Visible = True ' You can set this to True to see the PowerPoint files being opened
    
    PauseMacro 3 'seconds
    
    ' Open each PowerPoint file in the folder
    Do While pptFileName <> ""
        found = False
        
        ' Open PowerPoint presentation
        Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(folderPath & "\" & pptFileName)
        
        PauseMacro 3 'seconds
        
        ' Search for keyword in slides
        For Each pptSlide In pptPres.slides
            For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
                If pptShape.HasTextFrame Then
                    If InStr(1, pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, keyword, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        found = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next pptShape
            If found Then Exit For
        Next pptSlide
        
        PauseMacro 3 'seconds
        
        ' Close PowerPoint presentation
        pptPres.Close
        
        ' Write filename to worksheet if keyword is found
        If found Then
            ws.Cells(rowNum, 1).Value = pptFileName
            rowNum = rowNum + 1
        End If
        
        ' Get next PowerPoint file in the folder
        pptFileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    ' Quit PowerPoint application
    pptApp.Quit
    
    ' Clean up
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Search complete. Results written to worksheet."
End Sub
```